# servlet always showing null while execution

Tags: java, html, servlets

When i run search.html file it runs successfully but after entering the values the output is as shown in image [output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KaYa2.png) please help if possible. Odbc data source name is base and table name is tab, I am using Microsoft Access for data storage [Access](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WqyYZ.png)

database.java

```
import java.sql.*;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;

public class database {

public Connection connect;
public Statement stat;
public String query;
public ResultSet result;

public database()
{
    try
    {
        Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
        connect = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:odbc:base","","");
        stat = connect.createStatement();
    }catch(Exception e){}
}

}
```

search.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>Search</title>
</head>
<body>
<form action="search" method="get">
    <input type="number" name="ref" placeholder="reference" />
    <input type="submit" value="search" />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

search.java

```
import java.io.*;
import java.sql.SQLException;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;


@WebServlet("/search")
public class search extends HttpServlet {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

/**
 * @see HttpServlet#HttpServlet()
 */
public search() {
    super();
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

/**
 * @see HttpServlet#doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse   response)
 */
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    response.setContentType("text/html");
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
    database DB = new database();

    DB.query = "SELECT * FROM tab where ref="
            +request.getParameter("ref");
    out.println("<html><body><table border=\"2\">"
            +"<tr><th>ref</th><th>des</th><th>pri</th><th>cat</th>"
            +"</tr>");

    try
    {
        DB.result=DB.stat.executeQuery(DB.query);
        while(DB.result.next())
        {
            out.println("<tr>"
                    +DB.result.getInt("ref")
                    +DB.result.getString("des")
                    +DB.result.getDouble("pri")
                    +DB.result.getString("cat")
                    +"</tr>");

        }
        out.println("</table></body></html>");
    }catch(Exception e){
        out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
}

/**
 * @see HttpServlet#doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
 */
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    doGet(request, response);
}

}
```

Comment: For some or the other reason I'm not able to view your output image.

Comment: The exception handling is wrong. You're merely printing the exception message which happens to be `"null"`. Replace `out.println(e.getMessage())` by `throw new ServletException(e)`. You'll get an error page and full stack trace in server log which usually already represents the whole answer in its own. Most likely `DB.stat` returned `null` which causes a `NullPointerException`.

Answer (score -1):

Though your following classes look nice but try out the following changes:

**database.java**

```
public class database {

public Connection connect;
public String query;
public ResultSet result;

public Connection databaseConnect()
{
    try
    {
        Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
        connect = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:odbc:base","","");
        return connect;
    }catch(Exception e){}
}

}
```

**search.java**

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) 
throws ServletException, IOException {
try{
Connection con = database.databaseConnect();
Statement stat = con.createStatement();
response.setContentType("text/html");
PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
//database DB = new database();

String query = "SELECT * FROM tab where ref="
        +request.getParameter("ref");
out.println("<html><body><table border=\"2\">"
        +"<tr><th>ref</th><th>des</th><th>pri</th><th>cat</th>"
        +"</tr>");

    result=stat.executeQuery(query);
    while(result.next())
    {
        out.println("<tr>"
                +result.getInt("ref")
                +result.getString("des")
                +result.getDouble("pri")
                +result.getString("cat")
                +"</tr>");

    }
    out.println("</table></body></html>");
}catch(Exception e){
    e.printStackTrace();
}
}
```

Comment: I am really sorry i messed it up while uploading, it still shows null after removing that semi-colon

Comment: Error Database cannot be resolved. In    Connection con = Database.database();

Comment: That's because I have mistakenly written _Database_ instead of _database_ , as described in your question. Made that change to my answer accordingly along with other changes. Do check that out.

Comment: I have a 64 bit office and 64 bit jvm so i rewrote the code with different syntax